# Evaluating an integral $\int \sqrt{x^{2k}+x^{-2k} - 1} dx$ (encountered in pursuit problem)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Evaluate the indefinite integral $$\int \sqrt{x^{2k}+x^{-2k}-1} dx$$ where $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

Source of inspiration: The pursuit problem of fox on rabbit.
Rabbit with speed $v_R$ starts from origin and runs along Y-axis in the XY plane whereas the fox with speed $v_F$ starts from point $(C,0)$ and pursues the rabbit at time $t=0$ (both start at this time).
Thus position of the rabbit is $(0, v_Rt)$ as a function of time $t$. Let the position of the fox be $(x(t), y(t))$. Then we obtain the differential equations
$$ x' = -v_F\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+(v_Rt-y)^2}}$$
and $$y'= v_F\frac{v_Rt-y}{\sqrt{x^2+(v_Rt-y)^2}} $$
Put $y= v_Rt-Y$ and $x=X$ to get
$$ X' = -v_F\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$$
and $$Y'=v_R - v_F\frac{Y}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} $$
Note that $$d\left(\log_e\left(\frac YX+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac YX\right)^2}\right)\right) = \frac1{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac YX\right)^2}}\cdot \frac{XdY-YdX}{X^2}= \frac1X \cdot \frac{XdY-YdX}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$$
Therefore we get $$0 = \frac{X'Y'-Y'X'}{X} = \frac{v_F}X \cdot \frac{XY'-YX'}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} + v_R\frac{X'}{X}$$
which on integrating gives us $$v_F\log_e \left(\frac YX + \sqrt{1+\left(\frac YX\right)^2}\right) + v_R\log_e X= v_R\log_e C$$ considering the initial condition (position $(C,0)$ of fox).
Therefore $Y+\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}=X(\frac CX)^{\frac{v_R}{v_F}}$ and on simplifying we get
$$Y = X\left[u^{k}-u^{-k}\right]$$ where $u=\frac XC$ and $k=-\frac{v_R}{v_F}$.
Substituting this in the differential equation for $X'$ we obtain
$$X' = -\frac{v_F}{\sqrt{u^{2k}+u^{-2k}-1}}$$
and to solve this the integral in the title needs to be evaluated.

Comment: See my answer below.